# Having trouble posting to Mongo DB after external API Call

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await

I'm attempting to make a fetch call to News API and populate my Articles collection in Mongo DB with the data I fetch. I have two files: articles.js, and article.js. - my schema looks like the following:

```
// Article.js 

const ArticleSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    author: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    url: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    datePublished: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    source: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})
```

In articles.js, this is what my route looks like. My logic is that I make my fetch call, wait for the JSON to return, then iterate thru that json and map all the information I need to new story objects. Once I have those objects - I want to create a new instance of an Article for each, then post them to my Articles collection in Mongo DB.

```
/ @route POST /articles -> adds new instance of an article to the database
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=entertainment&apiKey=63c967f7cbd84c11b263b4e4758f1693');
        const data = await res.json();

 
        data.articles.forEach(article => {
            const storyData = {
                title: article.title,
                author: article.author,
                description: article.description,
                url: article.url,
                datePublished: article.publishedAt,
                source: article.source.name
            }
            // console.log(storyData)

            new Article(storyData)
                .save()
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message)
        res.status(400).json({ message: err.message })
    }
})
```

After my forEach loop, I get the objects like so:

```
 {
    title: `'Matrix 4' Style "Shifted" From Original Trilogy, Says Neil Patrick Harris - Hollywood Reporter`,
    author: 'Ryan Parker',
    description: 'The actor, who appears in the fourth installment, called the upcoming film "ambitious."',
    url: 'https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/matrix-4-style-shifted-from-original-trilogy-says-neil-patrick-harris',
    datePublished: '2020-09-16T17:54:26Z',
    source: 'Hollywood Reporter'
  }
```

I'm able to get the objects I'd like with the data I need, however when I attempt to call .save(), I receive validation error similar to the following:

"ValidationError: article validation failed: author: Path `author` is required."

I'm thinking that it may have to do with the fact that when I make post to the DB, the request should list something along the lines of "title: req.body.title", etc... Any thoughts on what could be causing this? My goal is to simply post these to the DB as I create them. Thanks!!!